# Is SQLite syntax the same for all platforms?

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, sqlite

First of all, if this question is a duplicate, or too broad, please guide me into the right topic, and I will delete the question.

I'm following this tutorial: [Using SQLite With C#](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/157830-using-sqlite-with-c#/#/), and I'm trying to add ORDER BY , and LIMIT clauses to the sql queries.

My question is, should I search for "how to ORDER BY in SQLite with C#" , or is the syntax for SQLite queries is the same for all platforms (C# , PHP, Android) ? So, will a single answer work for all SQLite implementations ? And is there a good resource for such queries?

Comment: One of the reason why SQL was introduced was to be a "Standard". So if you understand one SQL dialect (e.g. SQLite) you can adapt easy to any other.

Comment: SQL of SQLITE is the same for all programming languages

Comment: @nabuchodonossor and Tinwor, I'm already familiar with MySQL. So will all my MySQL queries work for SQLite too ?

Comment: @CengizFrostclaw Most of the more simple ones will (`SELECT`, `UPDATE` and such), but once you get into more complicated stuff like triggers and stored procs you will find differences.

Comment: @Vache thanks, I guess the most complicated things will be ORDER and LIMIT for me :) I was confused with the way this tutorial makes queries. But I tried same queries with MySQL, and they work too. Thanks for all the help !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The SQLite syntax (and the SQL standard) is clearly defined and doesn't depend on the API you are using: https://www.sqlite.org/lang.html

C#, Java or any other language might have different objects to interact with the database, the result sets and other database related things, but SQL is SQL and it stays the same.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I would picture it.  SQL is a broad generic language, like English.  There are a lot of dialects/variations (like American, Australian, etc) of it that can be used like SQLite, MySQL, etc.  But when speaking a particular dialect, let's say SQLite, that language is the same no matter what.  But just because the words are the same, there are different ways of communicating that language (let's say email vs handwriting a letter).  While the words are exactly the same, it's just a different way of conveying them.  You can think of the various computer languages (C#, PHP, etc) as different methods for conveying the SQL words you want to the database.  So if you want to talk to a database, you 1) Need to figure out what you'll say to it (figure out the SQL).  Then 2) Figure out how you'll send the message (what computer  language).

Hope that helps!